# Looping through registry keys stored in an list

Tags: python, regedit

I have a few Windows Registry keys stored in a python list from a file. The keys are stored as full paths, and I just want to make sure they exist by looping through the list one element at a time.

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunServicesOnce
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunServicesOnce
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunServices
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\Notify
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\Userinit
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\\Shell
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\\Shell
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ShellServiceObjectDelayLoad
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnceEx
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer\Run
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer\Run
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows\load
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\SharedTaskScheduler
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows\\AppInit_DLLs
```

The above are the keys I am checking for existence and the contents of my `keys.txt` file.

```
keysFile = 'keys.txt'
with open(keysFile) as f:
    keys = f.readlines()
keys = [x.strip() for x in keys]
```

The code above is for opening the file with the paths , and storing each line as an element of a list. I am just lost on how to use those paths to check if they exist. I have seen `winreg` being used, but I'm not sure if that would apply to this as these are full paths. I will take any guidance on how to navigate this situation. I am new to both python and the registry so please be patient. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know of python modules for dealing with the registry (although they likely exist). I personally would approach the problem with a mix of string formatting, and the `os` module, while using [this wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Registry#Command_line_editing). I think it would look something like:

```
import os
for key in keys: # you made this list already
    command = "Reg.exe QUERY {}".format(key) # apply string formatting to replace the {}
    os.system(command) # call our command on the command line
```

There is probably a great deal to know about Registry scripting, but once you find the commands you want you would just substitute them in! Hopefully this is enough to get you started, welcome to StackOverflow XD!